# What is the name of the install package and how to make it visible in Recovery mode?

Tags: recovery-mode

Issue; when downloaded to a Mac, the .zip file was unzipped.  The issue was resolved by downloading files from the vendor with Windows.

The goal is to install the factory [Android 10 ROM](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/operating-system/tc72-operating-system-for-gms-devices.html):

### [HE_FULL_UPDATE_10-16-10.00-QG-U00-STD-HEL-04.zip](https://www.zebra.com/apps/dlmanager?dlp=-227178c9720c025483893483886ea540bd07dd0f9873752cf891686eb495040ba85f97bf163f9fd12080ee1978f57c98463270ae549b1b51ba0181bc2a6ca2164e38df8708ace657df2557c4215aadff92bcdb7aea5f4ef938da121c42b13e7ae4e14ec2557f2ea77adf0d033c313e1f23637ada9eaf2f0&c=us&l=en)

and wipe the existing configured ROM.   The .zip file contents were copied to a micro SD card, which was installed in the Android device.

From Android Recovery Mode, I tried to install the files that were visible, however the failures returned are captured on the photo:

[image]

A list of files is returned by user@mac HE_FULL_UPDATE_10-16-10 % `find .`

```
./compatibility.zip
./.DS_Store
./care_map.pb
./META-INF
./META-INF/.DS_Store
./META-INF/com
./META-INF/com/.DS_Store
./META-INF/com/symbol
./META-INF/com/symbol/DeviceManifest.xml
./META-INF/com/android
./META-INF/com/android/otacert
./META-INF/com/android/metadata
./payload_1.bin
./payload_properties.txt
./payload_properties_1.txt
./payload.bin
```

For some reason not all file are displayed in Android Recovery Mode.   Which file is the to be selected and how to enable its selection from the Android Recovery Mode?

## Attempt to flash .zip file failed:

[image]

Comment: For some reason, when the zip file was download to my Mac it was automatically unzipped into a folder.  I compressed the folder into a .zip file, copied it to the SD card.   The photo shows the results of attempts to install.

Comment: you must not zip the parent folder, only the subfolders and files. or tell your mac to just download the file. if zebra respect the standard file layout, recovery is looking for *META-INF/com/google/android/updater-script* inside the zip file (which seems missing) but of course vendors can have their own layout (like HTC)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

flashable UPDATE.ZIP must not extracted. flash the file as it is